# Is there any way to connect to postgresql in xamarin?

Tags: postgresql, xamarin

I am working with a cross platform app project and have to use postgresql as server.
I have found NpgSql but it does not work on PCL.
Is there any way to connect to postgresql?

Thanks

Comment: "does not work" ... how exactly? Your best bet might be to patch nPgSQL so it supports the Xamarin Portable Class Libraries (assuming that's the "PCL" you mean). If it's not depending too heavily on low level language features or system libraries you can't use, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look if there is a .net library that can be used in android or iOS project and then call in PCL project via dependency Service.

Otherwise a solution could be Binding a Java library for Android.

If I should work with this db, I would prefer to write some webservices

Comment: The main .net client library for PostgreSQL is nPgSQL, and the original poster has said it doesn't work with PCL - presumably referring to the Xamarin Portable Class Libraries.

Comment: @CraigRinger ok you can try to use nPgSql on Android project that is not PCL and then call it on PCL project using Dependency Service

Comment: nPgSql does not support to Android project with mono android 5.0